# ¿Cómo modificar los ejes de coordenadas en un DCA plot?

Tags: r

Me gustaría poder modificar los ejes de coordenadas en un plot que obtengo tras realizar un análisis estadístico (DCA). Este es un ejemplo (a pequeña escala) de los datos a analizar en el plot:

```
  library(vegan)
  library(reshape2)

  Animal = sample(0:30,3800,replace = T)
  Numero = sample(0:500,3800,replace = T)
  df<-as.data.frame(cbind(Animal,Numero))
  Matrix_df<-acast(df,Animal~Numero,fill = 0 )
```

Este es el análisis estadístico (DCA) donde ordena los datos dependiendo de los valores compartidos entre ambos ejes de la matriz:

```
  DCA.df <- decorana(Matrix_df)

 plot(DCA.df, origin = TRUE, 
 display = "sites",
 type = "n",
 cex.main = 0.75,
 cex.axis=0.75,
 cex.lab=0.75,
 axes =FALSE, 
 xlim=c(-4,4), 
 ylim=c(-4,4),
 main = "Raw data",
 xlab = "DCA1 (0.353)",
 ylab = "DCA2 (0.247)")

 points (DCA.df)
```

La única manera factible de cambiarlos es usando este script

```
  axis(1, at=c(-4,-2,0,2,4))
  axis(2, at=c(-4,-2,0,2,4))
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto obtengo un espacio muy grande entre el eje x e y 
[image: DCA plot]

¿Cómo puedo juntarlo? ¿Cuál es mi fallo? ¿Existe otra manera más fácil de modificar los ejes dependiendo de mis necesidades?

Además me gustaría que el título del xlab y del ylab estuviera más junto al plot ¿Cómo podría juntarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en los valores de `xlim` e `ylim`, simplemente son demasiado grandes en relación a la muestra. Podrías eventualmente ajustarlos de forma automática en función a los datos, por ejemplo de la siguiente forma:

```
######################################################################
# Calculo de ejes y límites
######################################################################
limx <- c(min(scores(DCA.df,display="sites")[,1]), 
          max(scores(DCA.df,display="sites")[,1]))
limy <- c(min(scores(DCA.df,display="sites")[,2]), 
          max(scores(DCA.df,display="sites")[,2]))

limx <- ifelse(limx<0,floor(limx),ceiling(limx))
limy <- ifelse(limy<0,floor(limy),ceiling(limy))

axx <- seq(limx[1],limx[2])
axy <- seq(limy[1],limy[2])

######################################################################
# Plot de los datos
######################################################################
plot(DCA.df, origin = TRUE, 
     display = "sites",
     type = "n",
     cex.main = 0.75,
     axes = FALSE, 
     xlim = limx, 
     ylim = limy,
     main = "Raw data",
     xlab="", 
     ylab=""
)

title(xlab = paste("DCA1 (", round(DCA.df$evals.decorana[1],4), ")"), line = 2, cex.lab = 0.75,)
title(ylab = paste("DCA2 (", round(DCA.df$evals.decorana[2],4), ")"), line = 2, cex.lab = 0.75,)
points (DCA.df)
axis(1, at=axx) 
axis(2, at=axy)
```

- Mediante [`scores()`](http://cc.oulu.fi/~jarioksa/softhelp/vegan/html/scores.html) obtenemos los valores de los ejes y calculamos el máximo y mínimo
- Estos valores los llevamos al siguiente número entero en caso que sea positivo y al anterior si es negativo, por ej: `c(-1.4512, 2,1589) -> c(-2,3)`. Estos serían nuestros `xlim` y `ylim`
- Luego para graficar los ejes, simplemente hacemos una secuencia de enteros entre el límite inferior y superior.
- Para ajustar los títulos de los ejes, verás que los termino definiendo mediante `title()`, el valor de `DCA1` y `DCA2` también lo dibujamos automáticamente (no sé si es el correcto) y con el parámetro `line` establecemos la separación entre título y eje.

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Genial!!, funciona tanto la unión de los ejes de coordenadas como unirlos la etiqueta con los ejes. Muchas gracias